# JQuery data html attribute not returning value

Tags: jquery, html

Here is my html:

```
<ul class="inboxList">
    <li data-selecttype='global|mailbox|inbox'>Inbox</li>
</ul>
```

And here is my jquery code:

```
$(".inboxList").children().each(function(child){
    console.log($(child).data("selecttype"));
});
```

I also tried taking out the $() in the child:

```
$(".inboxList").children().each(function(child){
    console.log(child.data("selecttype"));
});
```

But that didn't work.

My return values are null and undefined. I was expecting the return value to be `global|mailbox|inbox` What am I doing incorrectly?

Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: like PSL said, just use $(this).  It'll make your life easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong argument from [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/)'s callback. You should use the second arg for the element  or ditch the args and just use `this`. it should be:

```
$(".inboxList").children().each(function(i, child){ // each has 2 args first one is index and second one is the element.
    console.log($(child).data("selecttype")); //Or this

    console.log($(this).data('selecttype'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JUyHg/

> .each( function(index, Element) )

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(".inboxList").children().each(function(){
    console.log($(this).data("selecttype"));
});
```

According to the definition on jQuery's site, .each() takes 2 arguments, `index` and `Element`, where,

> index - is the index of the current matched element in the jQuery object
>   returned by .each()

And

> Element - is the current element, in your case
>
> ```
> <li data-selecttype=​"global|mailbox|inbox">​Inbox​</li>​
> ```

Read more about [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d3athR0n/FkNTe/)